# how to connect to OBD-sensor with python?

Tags: python, obd-ii

I can't reach connect to the remote obd-sensor. Tried it out with the python-obd but there is no explanation about remote connection (Connection through the phone text messages is good). In the [python-obd doc](https://python-obd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Connections/) I see only "connection string" without any explanations what is that string and how to create it.
So this code:

```html
import obd
from obd import OBDStatus
connection = obd.OBD("61.144.222.116:2332")
print(OBDStatus.NOT_CONNECTED)
```

returns just

```html
[obd.elm327] [Errno 2] could not open port 61.144.222.116:2332: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '61.144.222.116:2332'
```

So I can't do anything with it. Model of sensors is SC20.

Answer (score 0):

The "connection string" is the name of the RS-232 serial port where your OBD is connected.  OBDs have to be plugged in to your computer directly.  You can't connect over a phone or over the internet.

It's possible to get OBD Bluetooth dongles that can be read remotely.